# WooCommerce: modify Layered Nav Widget output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to modify WooCommerce's Layered Nav Widget output so that it wraps each widget's instance into a `<div>` tag and add an additional class based on the current attribute slug to each `<li>` element.

I know how to do that, but I don't want to alter the original widget file.

Is there any way to substitute the original WooCommerce widget file with modified one as I can do with WooCommerce templates?

I suppose I can also put a custom function into functions.php but the level of my experience advises I can't do that myself.